# Method returns early before Axios returns fetched data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

I'm fetching data from server using axios.post method but it returns early .I have used async and await but data is not updated

apiService.js

```
export const  getAppAuthUser = async (page, authorizedType) => {

    await axios.post(APIURL.apiURL, JSON.stringify({
        page: page,
        authorized: authorizedType
    }), {
        headers: {

            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.data;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

component.js

```
import * as Users from '../api/apiService';
class User extends Component {
    sortedInfo = {};
    componentDidMount() {
        this.data=Users.getAppAuthUser(1,true);
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}
```

when I console it return Promise {}

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `async` functions do: they return promises. `async/await` exists to make the syntax for working with promises easier, but it does not change the fact that promises are involved. To get the value inside the promise, you'll need to use the promise's `.then` method, or put your code in an async function and await its result.

You also have a problem in your getAppAuthUser function that you're not returning anything, and so the promise will resolve to undefined. It's a lot easier to make this kind of problem when you're mixing the `.then` style with the `async/await` style. I'd strongly recommend just picking one style and using that consistently.

```
export const getAppAuthUser = async (page, authorizedType) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(APIURL.apiURL, JSON.stringify({
      page: page,
      authorized: authorizedType
    }), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    console.log(res);
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

import * as Users from '../api/apiService';
class User extends Component {
    sortedInfo = {};
    async componentDidMount() {
        this.data = await Users.getAppAuthUser(1,true);
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes your right..Can we use data await inside setState() like this  :- this.setState({ data: await Users.getAppAuthUser(1,true)});

Comment: If the code is surrounded by an async function, yes.

Comment: Its calling api 2 times

Comment: if we follow this way how to error handle.like if api throws bad gateway ,in this case how to handle it

Comment: Error handling goes in the catch block. I mimicked your code and kept the catch inside getAppAuthUser, but if you prefer you could delete it from there and do the catch in componentDidMount.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is asynchronous, we can't use like this `this.data=Users.getAppAuthUser(1,true)`  if you wish to use same like this then use `async-await` like this `async componentDidMount() {
        this.data= await Users.getAppAuthUser(1,true);
        console.log(this.data);
    }`

Or you can use promise like this `Users.getAppAuthUser(1,true).then(data=>{
console.log(data);
})`